# Regex to escape double quote in a Json Value in Java

Tags: java, json, regex

I have a JSON string which might have unescaped double quotes characters in the JSON value part. I am trying to capture them using regex and escape using `java.util.regex.Matcher` and later convert the complete JSON string to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` object. 
So that,

This becomes:

```
{
  "DESC1":"Steve"s and Carl"s " Car",
  "DESC2": "Steve's and Carl"s Car",
  "DESC3": """,
  "DESC4": "Steve and Carl"
}
```

This

```
{
  "DESC1":"Steve\"s and Carl\"s \" Car",
  "DESC2": "Steve's and Carl\"s Car",
  "DESC3": "\"",
  "DESC4": "Steve and Carl"
}
```

So far I am able to think of following regex(I am not an expert), but it is not targeting all the 3 cases.

```
:\s*"(.*(").*)"
```

How could this regex be improved?

Comment: `I have a JSON string which might have unescaped double quotes characters` ... then it is not valid JSON, and could not have been generated by any Java JSON library.  What is the source of this broken JSON, and why can't you fix it there?

Comment: If there are no nested curly braces, perhaps this might work https://ideone.com/7lAKRT

Answer (score 1):

If this value string;

```
str = str.replaceAll("\/","");
```

Make "/" change ""(EMPTY).

or

```
try {
     FileReader reader = new FileReader("JSON file path");
     JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
     String jsonString = jsonParser.parse(reader).toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For JSONParser

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the example data, you could match the key part and in the value part make use of `\G` to get repetitive matches asserting the position at the end of the previous match.

To make sure there is at least an opening and a closing curly brace you could make use of [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Java does not support infinite lookbehind, but is does support finite lookbehind by specifying a number for the quantifier.

In this example a I have chosen `{0,1000}` but you can of course change that to your requirement.

```
(?<=\\{[^\\{}]{0,1000})("[^\r\n"{}]+":\s*"|\G(?!^))([^"\r\n{}]*)(")(?=[^{}]*})(?!\s*(?:,|$))
```

In Java

```
final String regex = "(?<=\\{[^\\{}]{0,1000})(\"[^\\r\\n\"\\{}]+\":\\s*\"|\\G(?!^))([^\"\\r\\n\\{}]*)(\")(?=[^\\{}]*\\})(?!\\s*(?:,|$))";
```

In the replacement use the 3 capturing groups:

```
String subst = "$1$2\\\\$3";
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/F1YVSE)

**Pattern parts**

- `(?<=` Finite positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `{[^{}]{0,1000}` Match `{` followed by 0 - 1000 times not `{` or `}`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `(` Capturing **group 1**

  - `"[^\r\n"{}]+"` Match `"`, 1+ any char except what is in the character class
  - `:\s*"` Match `:`, 0+ whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match
- `)` Close group
- `([^"\r\n{}]*)` Capture **group 2**, match 0+ times any char except the listed
- `(")` Capture **group 3**, match `"`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^{}]*}` Match 0+ times any char except the listed, then match `}`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `\s*(?:,|$)` Match 0+ times a whitespace char, then match either `,` or end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

Result

```
{
  "DESC1":"Steve\"s and Carl\"s \" Car",
  "DESC2": "Steve's and Carl\"s Car",
  "DESC3": "\"",
  "DESC4": "Steve and Carl"
}
```